# Is it possible to use "man std::find" in linux?

Tags: c++, stl, manpage

I am using *Ubuntu*, and have already installed libstdc++6-4.7-doc .

But it seems `man` only works with classes, for example

```
$ man std::vector
$ man std::istream
```

works, but

```
$ man std::find
```

doesn't work, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**MODIFIED:**

after installing libstdc++???-doc

we can use  file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7-base/libstdc++/html/index.html
to access the documents.

Comment: `man std::vector` yields "No manual entry for std::vector" for me. How did you install this?

Comment: @JohnDibling It works for me (I am on archlinux)

Comment: @khajvah:  I'm on Ubuntu.  I'm sure I just need to install some package.

Comment: @JohnDibling I don't remember me installing anything additional but [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B+-doc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) may be the package

Comment: @JohnDibling, before you run man std::vector, please execute sudo apt-get install libstdc++????-doc first.

Comment: Got the man pages.  Running `man -k . | grep std` results in nothing that looks like any components from `<algorithm>`.  I suspect they aren't there at all.

Comment: The actual docs are all in html format; the classes (like `std::vector`) have man pages automatically generated by Doxygen, but Doxygen only cares about html output anyways.

Answer (score 2):

when you try man [something] u'r just pulling up the man page for that item (based on how the 'man' binary is working). since find isn't working its likely that there is no man find page to bring up. if you really wanna learn more c++ lib features from the algorithms lib visit here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

man isn't always the best resource (altho often a great starting point)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On *ubuntu* no package contains the std::find manpage.

If those *algorithm* manpages are important for you, file a bug report to *ubuntu* or be a volunteer...